# Merging onehotencoder values together in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I am completing my data science project and want to merge data using get_dummies pandas library

my df :

```
    0_A  0_B 0_C  1_A 1_B 1_C
0   1    0   0     0  1   0
1   0    1   0     1  0   0
2   0    1   0     0  0   1
```

Output :

```
  A    B   C  
0   1    1   0     
1   1    1   0     
2   0    1   1
```

tried using if statement but no luck

Regards 
Saif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={"0_A":[0,1,1],
                       "0_B":[1,0,0],
                       "0_C":[0,1,1],
                       "1_A":[0,0,0],
                       "1_B":[0,1,0],
                       "1_C":[0,0,1]})
final_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A","B","C"])

for i in final_df:
    final_df[i] = (df[df.columns[df.columns.str.contains(i)]].max(axis=1))

print(final_df)
```

```
    A   B   C
0   1   1   0
1   1   1   0
2   0   1   1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can just use bitwise OR between columns, like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO("""
    0_A  0_B 0_C  1_A 1_B 1_C
0   1    0   0     0  1   0
1   0    1   0     1  0   0
2   0    1   0     0  0   1 """), sep=r"\s+")

df["A"] = df["0_A"] | df["1_A"]
df["B"] = df["0_B"] | df["1_B"]
df["C"] = df["0_C"] | df["1_C"]

df = df[["A", "B", "C"]]

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C
0  1  1  0
1  1  1  0
2  0  1  1
```